# CJ webservice problem

Tags: php, web-services, cj

i'm using cj web service for searching products using php soap.

using advertiserid 2288710(TicketNetwork).Already created relationship with this advertiser. While using this php code i'm getting total result=0

```
$developerKey = "my developer id here";
$websiteId = "my web site id here";

$ini = ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0");

try {

$client = new SoapClient("https://product.api.cj.com/wsdl/version2/productSearchServiceV2.wsdl", array('trace'=> true));

$results = $client->search(array("developerKey" => $developerKey,
"websiteId" => $websiteId,
"advertiserIds" => '2288710',
"keywords" => 'lady gaga',
"serviceableArea" => 'US',
"sortBy" => 'price',
"sortOrder" => 'asc',
"maxResults" => 10));

// The entire response structure will be printed in the next line
echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

if suppose i'm using "advertiserIds" => '', it will return whole result, but i need only result from that advertiser. I also tried with 'joined' keyword, for that also i'm getting no result.

please anyone help me to figure out whats going on.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request matches their documentation example.  The only thing I can think is are you sure your accepted into the program, and not just "pending" acceptance?
http://help.cj.com/en/web_services/web_services.htm#product_catalog_search_service_rest.htm